# Finding the rotation angle $\theta$ of a 2x2 unitary matrix

Tags: pauli-gates, unitarity, linear-algebra

We can represent a 2x2 unitary matrix as follows:
$$U = \cos(\theta)I - i \sin(\theta) \vec{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma},$$
where $\vec{n} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)$. This can be viewed as a rotation around the axis $\vec{n}$ on a Block sphere by angle $\theta$.

Given a numerical representation of $U$
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
what is the easiest way to extract the angle $\theta$?

Comment: theta=arccos(a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can actually guarantee $U = \cos\theta I - i \sin \theta\vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}$, then we can see that $\text{Re}[a] = \text{Re}[d] = \cos \theta$ and so
$$
\theta = \arccos \left( \text{Re}[a] \right). \tag{1}
$$

---

For completeness, we should consider when there might be an unknown global phase (e.g. Nielsen and Chuang exercise 4.8). In this case, we are instead interested in the unitary
$$
U = \exp(i\alpha) \left(\cos\theta I - i \sin \theta\vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}\right). \tag{2}
$$
We equate the two expressions for $U$ for the diagonal elements,
\begin{align}
a &= (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)(\cos \theta - i \sin\theta n_z) \tag{3} \\
d &= (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta n_z) \tag{4}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\text{Re}[a + d] &= 2 \cos \alpha \cos \theta \tag{5} \\
\text{Im}[a + d] &= 2 \sin \alpha \cos \theta \tag{6}\\
\end{align}
So first solve for
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \arctan \left(\frac{\text{Im}[a + d]}{\text{Re}[a + d]} \right), \tag{7}
\end{equation}
and then plug this into Eq. (5) to find
\begin{equation}
\theta = \arccos \left( \frac{\text{Re}[a + d]}{2 \cos \alpha}\right). \tag{8}
\end{equation}
You might have to be careful because of the periodicity of $\tan \alpha$ that gets lost in Eq. (7).

Answer (score 2):

Taking trace of a unitary $U{=}\cos(\theta)\mathbb{I}-i\sin(\theta)\vec{n}.\vec{\sigma}$ leads to $Tr(U){=}2\cos(\theta)$, from which you can calculate $\theta{=}\cos ^{-1}\frac{Tr(U)}{2}$. In general, your numerical matrix can lead to a global phase which you can eliminate by taking the absolute of the trace, i.e. your solution for $\theta{=}\cos ^{-1}\frac{|Tr(U)|}{2}$, in terms of your matrix element, this becomes $\theta{=}\cos ^{-1}\frac{|a+d|}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I have code to compute the angle and axes [here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/solovay_kitaev.py):

```
def u_to_bloch(u):
  """Compute angle and axis for a unitary."""

  angle = np.real(np.arccos((u[0, 0] + u[1, 1]) / 2))
  sin = np.sin(angle)
  if sin < 1e-10:
    axis = [0, 0, 1]
  else:
    nx = (u[0, 1] + u[1, 0]) / (2j * sin)
    ny = (u[0, 1] - u[1, 0]) / (2 * sin)
    nz = (u[0, 0] - u[1, 1]) / (2j * sin)
    axis = [nx, ny, nz]
  return axis, 2 * angle
```